# Composition of function over a disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

It is considered the disc $\mathbb{D} = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ and $f$ defined only over that disc such that $f(0,0) = 0, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = 0 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^2}(0,0) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}(0,0) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(0,0)$. Let $g(x,y) := \sqrt{f(x,y)}$. I am asked to show that the function $g$ is continuous, that both partial derivatives of first order exist, and that it is differentiable, everything at $(0,0)$.

I know that $\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{D} \ \{(0,0)\}$, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{f(x,y)}} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. However, in $(0,0)$, when I apply the limit, I get that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(t,0)-g(0,0)}{t} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0 } \frac{\sqrt{f(t,0)}}{t}$$I don't know how to continue. I was wondering if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(t,0)=f(0,0)+t\frac {\partial f }{\partial x} (0,0)+(t^{2}/2)\frac {\partial^{2} f }{\partial^{2} x} (0,0)+o(t^{2})=o(t^{2})$. Hence, $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{f(t,0)}}{t}=0$.

Comment: I don't get why at the end $f$ is $o(t^2)$

Comment: It is the Taylor expansion up to the third degree term.  @DanielC.

Comment: Ok, it is because there was an $o(t)$ I think, now I understand why

Comment: Sorry about the typo. You can show that second partial derivative is also $0$ and derivative  is the linear map $L(x,y)\equiv 0$. @DanielC.

Comment: Correct, and therefore the differential at that point is $dg_{(0,0)} = 0$. Thanks